# Html nav bar on all pages without pasting code

Tags: javascript, html

So if I wanted to have a nav bar on my site is there any way to have a separate html file with the nav bar codes and a script in js or any language that simply takes the code of the nav bar file and puts it into another page. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Use a web component. This is too broad for the scope of stack overflow

Comment: You confusing XD

Comment: This is a very simple thing to do, and guides on this are abundant online. A quick Google would be enough for you to get your answer.

Comment: Just want to get good direct answer not a guide

Comment: @RichardCooper that's not what Stack Overflow is for. It's for asking questions about things you cannot find with a simple Google search. Here, people are expected to put at least some effort into finding an answer before asking a new question. Charlie is right, there's an abundant amount of information available on this on the web.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution to dynamically load a HTML file inside another HTML can be achieved by:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

then import the file using:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#navbar").load("./navbar.html"); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for not being like the others and giving the answer Imma go do the work now to test this

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/templates/#the-base-layout

> Each page in the application will have the same basic layout around a different body. Instead of writing the entire HTML structure in each template, each template will extend a base template and override specific sections.